# Cannot store and retrieve custom ItemProperties from AppointmentItem in case it is a recurring AppointmentItem

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I want to add some custom properties on an AppointmentItem.
This works perfectly for "normal" AppointmentItems.

Example:

```
myAppointment.ItemProperties.Add("MyId", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
MyId = (Outlook.UserProperty)myAppointment.ItemProperties["MyId"];
MyId.Value = myMeeting.id;
meetingId = myMeeting.id;
myAppointment.Save();
```

Even when I restart Outlook I can fetch those properties from the AppointmentItem like that:

```
MyId = (Outlook.UserProperty)theCurrentAppointment.ItemProperties["MyId"];
```

No problems so far.

Now when I use  the same method in AppointmentItems which represent ONE AppointmentItem within a recurrent appointment series it either does not store or cannot retrieve the MyItem property.

Anyone any idea why it behaves differently when it is a recurring AppointmentItem?

Comment: After some investigation I found out that a "normal" AppointmentItem contains the "MyId" no problem and a LOT OF ItemProperties while a recurring AppointmentItem contains much less ItemProperties (only 7) amongst others a "AppointmentItem" Property. But when I tried to assign it I get the following exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Mitglied nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))"

Comment: If you set a property on an instance of a recurring activity, you are creating an exception. Are you sure you are accessing the same exception next time? Or did you mean to set the properties on the master appointment rather than an occurrence?

Comment: FurthermorevI made sure that no referenced to the recurring AppointmentItem remain. For this I handle the Close event on the Inspector and null the static reference to the AppointmentItem

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko i open the occurence in outlook and then i hit the button of my addin to add the property. So i thought i would access the same occurence and not the master appointment when i would close and reopen the occurence in outlook. so the question is how can i make sure to access the right appointmentitem?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko and noni don’t want to set the property on the master but on the occurrence.

Comment: Firstly, Item.Properties.Add returns an ItemProperty object. There is no need to retrieve it (second line of your code). Secondly, have you tried to use UserProperties instead of ItemProperties? Thirdly, do you see that an exception is created in OUtlookSpy? - select the appointment, click IMessage button (OutlookSpy will prompt to open the master appointment). Do you see the embedded message attachment on the GetAttachmentTable tab? If yes, double click on the attachment, select the PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ property, right click, select IMAPIProp::OpenProperty, select IID_IMessage.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko There is one recurring test meeting where the coding above works. but for any other recurring meeting it doesn’t . So the question is what is the difference between ItemProperties and UserProperties and why should it help? Secondly , when I buy OutlookSpy and I would see the attachment as described above what would it help? Best regards Hannes

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I tried to install OutlookSpy. As I tested the Software 3 years ago I need to buy a license. As long as I cannot see how this resolves my problem I am a bit tentative :-) Secondly. I converted all ItemProperties to UserProperties. Stil same behavior. Any ideas? And still. Sometimes it works , sometimes it doesn't .... I couldnt find out what this causes this behaviour. Some timing condition when accessing the ItemProperties?

Comment: Are you using Exchange? It is known to stamp appointments with its own properties, causing Outlook to download the data from the server, whcih can wipe out your changes. Try to run Outlook in the offline mode - does your code always succeed?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I found some very usefull information: everytime when I add some text to the body (via the Outlook dialog, not via setting the appointmentItem..body = "xxx" it seems it also stores the UserProperties. Did you know that? BTW: It does not matter when I use Outlook offline or online. This didn't change the behaviour (and yes I am using Outlook in an Exchange environment)

Comment: Don't know. Probably timing.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko would you be interested to help me   resolve this problem in a payed way? we could arrange for a webex and you can access my dev environment and explain the code to you. the project is quite small do it might work

Comment: I am completely booked at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko what would be the esrliest to help or are you generally not interested?

Comment: I won't be available for the next couple months or so...

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko just öet me know when you are available again, or can you reconmend someone ?

Comment: Send me an email at dmitry (at) dimastr (dot) com, and we will discuss this privately.